# How wsimport utility tool create classes with package structure at backend ? What is the backgroud mechanism behind this?

Tags: web-services, soap, soap-client, wsimport, xmlbeans

I'm an intermediate java developer. I'm just curious how class files are generated when we use "wsimport xxxxx.wsdl" command. How does wsimport generate class files with package structure? Can we change the package name without modifying wsdl ?

In our organization, one webservice is deprecated and new webservice also uses the same package stucture and class names. How to change the package structure of the new webservice's generated class files?

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

To generate the classes of a wsdl in a specific package, use the following command from the wsimport tool:

wsimport -keep -p com.example